# Unlist (ungroup) a string df col into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I used the command to group. Now I want to 'ungroup' and get back the original df

example

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["abc", "abc","abc","def"],
    "col2": ["adam","eve","john","john"]
})
```

```
original_df.groupby('id').agg(
    unique_count_col2=('col2', 'nunique'),
    unique_values_col2=('col2', 'unique')
).reset_index()
```

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["abc", "abc","abc","def"],
    "col2": ["adam","eve","john","john"]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.explode()` the `unique_values_col2` column (but if you had duplicate `col2` values under `id` they are lost):

```py
out = (
    df[["id", "unique_values_col2"]]
    .rename(columns={"unique_values_col2": "col2"})
    .explode("col2")
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    id  col2
0  abc  adam
0  abc   eve
0  abc  john
1  def  john
```